# Converting JSON string to JSON Object having null value

Tags: java, json

```
String test ="{"abc":null}";
JSONObject testObj = new JSONObject(test);
```

giving error as abc is not a JSONObject. How can I convert this string to JSON Object?

In Actual implementation 'test' string i am reading from a file.. so escape sequence not added..!!

Comment: use this, String test ="{\"abc\":null}";

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation in your string is not alright.
Is abc an object? or is it just the string abc?

```
String test = "{" + "abc" + ":null}";
```

but in the above case, you should simply do:

```
String test = "{abc:null}";
```

Or if abc is another defined String variable, say like this:

```
String abc = "awesomeText";
String test = "{" + abc + ":null}";
```

Or maybe you need those quotes from abc? 
use "\" to escape the quote character. Like this:

```
String test ="{\"abc\":null}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this test and it worked fine for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.json"));

        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject testObj = new JSONObject(currentLine);
            System.out.println(testObj);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried many successful tests while playing with the content of the test.json file:

1. `{"abc":null}`
2. `{'abc':null}`
3. `{abc:null}`